# MySQL query - single product with multiple reviews

Tags: mysql, database

Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to offer!

I'm working with an a bit of an odd database where products are related via tags and are not hierarchical.

I'm trying to select a single product using a SKU number from a table and join it with a table of product reviews like so:

```
SELECT ims.master_sku, ims.title, ims.price, 
       ims.description, ir.mvp_number, ir.title,
       ir.review, ir.rating, ir.created_on
FROM default_inventory_master_skus AS ims
JOIN default_inventory_reviews AS ir
WHERE ims.master_sku = '22284319'
GROUP BY ir.review;
```

This gives me around 150 rows - which are all the same product but contain different reviews. My question is how can I return just the one product (as a single row) and somehow convert the reviews into columns associated with that one product?

Again - thank you for your time and help.

Rich

Comment: You want to convert 150 rows into 150 columns?  This is called pivoting the data, and MySQL is particularly bad at this operation.  I would suggest that you figure out another way to work with the results you have.

Comment: Do you realise that as this query stands, it links a single product from the master_skus table to **all** records on the reviews table, regardless of which product each review relates to?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, although it's not "relational".

Looks like someone wants this data in Excel ;).

With MySQL, you will need to generate an SQL statement and execute it.  Either within MySQL (in a procedure) or outside (e.g., in PHP).  Query first for the pivot column names, put together the statement, then execute it.

An idea of the implementation is here:

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78